# Create API endpoint for fetching dynamic data based on time

Tags: php, mysql, database, rest, codeigniter

I have a scraper which periodically scrapes articles from news sites and stores them in a database [MYSQL].
The way the scraping works is that the oldest articles are scraped first and then i move onto much more recent articles.

*For example* an article that was written on the **1st of Jan** would be scraped first and given an **ID 1**  and an article that was scraped on the **2nd of Jan** would have an **ID 2**.

So the recent articles would have a higher id as compared to older articles.

There are multiple scrapers running at the same time.

Now i need an endpoint which i can query based on timestamp of the articles and i also have a limit of 10 articles on each fetch.

The problem arises for example when there are **20 articles** which were posted with a timestamp of **1499241705** and when i query the endpoint with a timestamp of **1499241705** a check is made to give me all articles that is **>=1499241705** in which case i would always get the same 10 articles each time,changing the condition to a **>** would mean i skip out on the articles from **11-20**. Adding another where clause to check on **id** is unsuccessful because articles may not always be inserted in the correct date order as the scraper is running concurrently.

Is there a way i can query this end point so i can always get consistent data from it with the latest articles coming first and then the older articles.

**EDIT:**

```
   +-----------------------+
   |   id | unix_timestamp |
   +-----------------------+
   |    1 |   1000         |
   |    2 |   1001         |
   |    3 |   1002         |
   |    4 |   1003         |
   |   11 |   1000         |
   |   12 |   1001         |
   |   13 |   1002         |
   |   14 |   1003         |
   +-----------------------+
```

The last timestamp and ID is being sent through the **WHERE** clause.

E.g.
    `$this->db->where('unix_timestamp <=', $timestamp);
                $this->db->where('id <', $offset);
$this->db->order_by('unix_timestamp ', 'DESC');
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');`

On querying with a timestamp of 1003, ids 14 and 4 are fetched. But then during the next call, id 4 would be the offset thereby not fetching id 13 and only fetching id 3 the next time around.So data would be missing .

Comment: do you have duplicate articles in your DB, if yes, first fix that issue.

Comment: no duplicate articles just articles which may have been posted at the same time.

Comment: Why don't you order them by ID?

Comment: So, you **really** need to see what articles where written at a particular second/timestamp?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I need to fetch articles from newest to oldest timestamp values where there could be multiple articles with the same timestamp and since I'm using a limit I might get the same data over and over again

Comment: Can you assign an unique ID to each scrapper?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I can assign a unique ID to each scrapper,the websites that i am scraping the articles from already have their own id which i store so i don't scrape the same data twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148494/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-jude-fernandes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts: timestamp and id.

```
WHERE   timestamp <= $ts_leftoff
  AND ( timestamp <  $ts_leftoff
            OR id <= $id_leftoff )
ORDER BY (timestamp DESC, id DESC)
```

So, assuming `id` is unique, it won't matter if lots of rows have the same `timestamp`, the order is fully deterministic.

There is a syntax for this, but unfortunately it is not well optimized:

```
WHERE (timestamp, id) <= ($ts_leftoff, $id_leftoff)
```

So, I advise against using it.

More on the concept of "left off":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: id is unique but may not be in a sequence so there is a chance that data might be skipped as shown in the example in the question,would this solve that problem?

Comment: I assume `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  If you can insert rows out of order (out of timestamp order, that is), then the problem is really nasty.  The solution, I think, is to tell users "items arriving in the last few seconds may not yet be in the database" and "you can see only the news we have scraped; come back later for more". -- that is, set expectations low enough for the code to work.

Comment: I have done news scraping; I don't see the alleged problem as being that serious.

Comment: The issue arises because the scrapers run synchronously so all data is pulled from one newspaper and then the scraper moves onto the next.The articles could have been posted at anytime so when the data is sorted by time and then date ,they may not always be in sequence so a few articles might be skipped entirely and would never show up

Comment: Does `timestamp` come from the article?  Or from your cron job?  "Never show up"?  Is there only one pass through the data?

Comment: The timestamp comes from the article and is inserted into the db directly which is why when an order by is done on the timestamp,there is a very high chance that the ids are not in sequence so applying a < or <= operator does not always work.There is only 1 pass of the data so the only time it is sorted is when its being queried.

Comment: If you haven't yet loaded an article into the table, then you can't display it to the user.  The "left off" technique avoids duplicates/skipped ones, but it cannot deal with not-yet-loaded ones.  (`OFFSET` is subject to dups/skips.)

Comment: A few modifications to the query but managed to get it working,thank you very much.